# Get real path of a file on JSF application startup

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to get the real path of a file in a JSF application scoped Bean using :

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath(file)
```

The problem is that `getCurrentInstance()` is throwing a `NullPointerException` when the bean is initialized at application startup:

```
@ManagedBean(eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class EnvoiPeriodiqueApp implements Serializable {

    @PostConstruct
    public void initBean() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/");
    }

}
```

So I'm trying to find another way to get the real path of the file without using the `getCurrentInstance()` of JSF.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You do not need a real path in real applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [ExternalContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html) documentation

> If a reference to an ExternalContext is obtained during application
>   startup or shutdown time, any method documented as "valid to call this
>   method during application startup or shutdown" must be supported
>   during application startup or shutdown time. The result of calling a
>   method during application startup or shutdown time that does not have
>   this designation is undefined.

So, the [getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRealPath-java.lang.String-) is not *valid to call during application startup*, and throw an [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) (not a [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) like the question said).

However, the [getContext()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getContext--) is *valid to call during application startup*, and retrieve a [ServletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html). You can access the real path by the method [getRealPath()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath-java.lang.String-) of [ServletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html).

---

So, you an securely access the real path by the snippet bellow:

```
((ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getRealPath("/")
```

---

In your code, you can try this.

```
@ManagedBean(eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class EnvoiPeriodiqueApp implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initBean() {
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
        System.out.println(servletContext.getRealPath("/"));
    }
}
```