# jsf error with External Context

Tags: jsf

I downloaded a project which works with jsf. I have the following method

```
public String getMenu() throws Exception {
        StringWriter str;
        ExternalContext context;
        HttpSession session;
        MultiLinkTag tag;

        context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        session = (HttpSession) context.getSession(true);
        str = new StringWriter();
        tag = new MultiLinkTag();
        tag.writeMenu(context.getRealPath("/embedded_links.xml"), session, str);

        return str.toString();
    }
```

In the eclipse editor I have the message:

```
method getRealPath not defined for ExternalContext
```

The import of ExternalContext is:

```
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
```

How can I fix this error?. Do I need any external jar?

Comment: I googled and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468199/get-real-path-of-a-file-on-jsf-application-startup. Try to see the differences (it most likely is related to casting and then this code cannot work in another project so their examples are wrong)

Comment: `((ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getRealPath("/")`